# JQUERY Chaining With Process and Pipe Not Working For Me

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

[JSFiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/bgordon/L5eLs/)

Piping and chaining are new to me...

I am having an issue getting this little script to work.  I have an array of URLs that I need to synchronously trigger with AJAX. I need to wait for a success response from each url (some may have a delay since they will be running large SQL queries and building reports) before piping to the next iteration.  If it does not get a success, then whole process must stop.

I think I am close after much fiddling but you will see that it is not working right.  Perhaps one of you gurus can help me out on this?

```
    //counter
var i = 0;

//array of local urls that I need to trigger one after another
var arrValues = [
    "http://fiddle.jshell.net/",
    "http://fiddle.jshell.net/",
    "http://fiddle.jshell.net/"];

//the step i need to repeat until done
var step = (function () {

    //expect to see this alert called for each iteration (only happens once?)
    alert(arrValues[i]+i);

    var url = arrValues[i];
    var model = {};

    model.process = function () {
        log('Starting: ' + url + i);

        return $.ajax(url)
            .done(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            log(textStatus + ' ' + url + i + ' Done');
        })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            log(textStatus + ' Failed');
        });
    };

    return model;
}());

//just outputting to the div here
function log(message) {
    $("#output").append($("<div></div>").text(message));
}

//start the process
log("Starting To Build Report");

//iterate through the array
$.each(arrValues, function (intIndex, objValue) {

    // I need to wait for success before starting the next step or fail and throw
    // the errors below - you will see this does not work now and never gets to the 
    // .done or .fail or .always

    step.process().pipe( function () {
        i++;
        step.process();
    });

}).done(function () {
    log("The process completed successfully");
})
    .fail(function () {
    log("One of the steps failed");
})
    .always(function () {
    log("End of process");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there, but the details are all-important. The knack is :

- to modify `step` to be a function (not an object), which returns a function, which itself returns an observable object (ie. a jqXHR promise)
- to allow `step` to accept an incremental integer `i` as a parameter; this avoids the need to maintain a running `i` in an outer scope
- to build a `.then()` chain with each `then()` taking as its argument the function returned by `step()`
- to seed the `.then()` chain with a resolved Promise to get it started
- to attach the final `.done()`, `.fail()`, `.always()` to the end of the `then()` chain.

Note: From jQuery 1.8, `.pipe()` is deprecated in favour of a revised `.then()`.

Here's the code :

```
var arrValues = [
    "http://fiddle.jshell.net/",
    "http://fiddle.jshell.net/",
    "http://fiddle.jshell.net/"
];

function step(i) {
    return function() {
        var url = arrValues[i];
        log('Starting: ' + url + i);
        return $.ajax(url).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            log(textStatus + ' ' + url + i + ' Done');
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            log(textStatus + ' ' + url + i + ' Failed');
        });
    }
};

function log(message) {
    $("#output").append($("<div/>").text(message));
}

log("Starting To Build Report");

var p = $.Deferred().resolve().promise();
$.each(arrValues, function(i, url) {
    p = p.then(step(i));
});
p.done(function() {
    log("The process completed successfully");
}).fail(function() {
    log("One of the steps failed");
}).always(function() {
    log("End of process");
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/L5eLs/4/)